# How to convert Gazebo's ConstImageStamped to cv::Mat?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm having difficulty finding information on how to convert the Gazebo Image class to OpenCV's own cv::Mat. Was wondering if someone has a code snippet to help me out a little bit here.

I should mention that I have no intension of using ROS.

**More Information:**
I have a robot with a camera attached, using the standard camera model provided in Gazebo, it publishes a camera topic, you can then write a Gazebo subscriber to subscribe to the topic and obtain the image data. However! most developers who work in OpenCV need that image data to be in cv::Mat. This question is how to convert Gazebo Image data to OpenCV's cv::Mat.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14619/how-to-convert-gazebo%27s-constimagestamped-to-cv::mat?/) by [chutsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/482/chutsu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I finally found the solution, the following assumes your sensor in Gazebo outputs RGB data, the code to subscribe to the image topic and convert the Gazebo Image data to OpenCV cv::Mat is as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <gazebo/gazebo_config.h>
#include <gazebo/gazebo_client.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

#define IMAGE_TOPIC "~/quadrotor/camera/camera/link/camera/image"


void cb(ConstImageStampedPtr &msg)
{
    // std::cout << msg->image().width() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << msg->image().height() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << msg->image().pixel_format() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << std::endl;

    int width;
    int height;
    char *data;

    width = (int) msg->image().width();
    height = (int) msg->image().height();
    data = new char[msg->image().data().length() + 1];

    memcpy(data, msg->image().data().c_str(), msg->image().data().length());
    cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC3, data);

    cv::imshow("camera", image);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    delete data;  // DO NOT FORGET TO DELETE THIS, 
                  // ELSE GAZEBO WILL TAKE ALL YOUR MEMORY
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gazebo::client::setup(argc, argv);
    gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
    gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub;

    // setup
    node->Init();
    sub = node->Subscribe(IMAGE_TOPIC, cb);

    // loop
    while (true) {
        gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(10);
    }

    // clean up
    gazebo::client::shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Of particular interest is the four lines here:

```
    char *data;
    data = new char[msg->image().data().length() + 1];

    memcpy(data, msg->image().data().c_str(), msg->image().data().length());
    cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC3, data);
```

To convert the data, we first allocate memory for the `data` variable (+1 for null character at the end). We then copy the image message data from `msg->image().data().c_str()` to `data`. Then we use the information about the height and width of the image to form the `cv::Mat`. Don't forget to delete `data` with `delete`, else you're introducing memory leaks.

---

Originally posted by [chutsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/482/chutsu/) with karma: 36 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlosprados11](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27723/carlosprados11/) on 2021-11-10**:
Hello.

It works, but what about depth camera? How is possible to get a depth picture (cv::Mat) from ImageStamped data?

Thanks in advance